# gethostbyname fails with error 111 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: android, android-ndk, sockets, gethostbyname

The device does have network connectivity (WiFi and 3G).

Calling gethostbyname() returns NULL with errno 111 (ECONNREFUSED).

The same call works fine on osx and windows.

What could be the problem?

Best,

Comment: Also seen this with errno 13 (EACCES) – Permission Denied, which is also resolved by adding the INTERNET permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add permission to use Internet in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a not or wrong configured DNS server setting on your device. Be sure to check that. This is most probably a problem with your local WiFi network - probably there's no local DNS server.

Maybe you could also try disabling WiFi as DNS resolution should work automatically in your mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

`ECONNREFUSED` suggests that the DNS resolver on your device *may* have tried failing over to TCP/IP (instead of UDP) because the answer was too long to fit in a normal UDP response packet.

If the configured DNS servers don't support inbound DNS requests over TCP you'd get that error.

Client apps can't normally get `ECONNREFUSED` from a UDP socket because they're stateless.